# c# windows phone 8 app azure table storage error

Tags: c#, .net, json, azure, windows-phone-8

My app has been working fine up until today!I am querying my azure table storage (through the azure storage nuget) and now debugging through my app I get an error of:

> {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: **An unexpected 'EndOfInput' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected**. ---> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: An unexpected 'EndOfInput' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.JsonReaderExtensions.ValidateNodeType(JsonReader jsonReader, JsonNodeType expectedNodeType)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.JsonReaderExtensions.ReadNext(JsonReader jsonReader, JsonNodeType expectedNodeType)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.JsonReaderExtensions.ReadStartObject(JsonReader jsonReader)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ReadPayloadStartImplementation(ODataPayloadKind payloadKind, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Boolean isReadingNestedPayload, Boolean allowEmptyPayload)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ReadPayloadStart(ODataPayloadKind payloadKind, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Boolean isReadingNestedPayload, Boolean allowEmptyPayload)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementation()
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously()
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.Read()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableOperationHttpResponseParsers.TableQueryPostProcessGeneric[TElement,TQueryType](Stream responseStream, Func`6 resolver, HttpWebResponse resp, TableRequestOptions options, OperationContext ctx, String accountName)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass10`2.b__f(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, OperationContext ctx)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ProcessEndOfRequest[T](ExecutionState`1 executionState)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndOperation[T](ExecutionState`1 executionState)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.EndExecuteQuerySegmented[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   Request Information
>   RequestID:f08895a8-0002-0048-6252-e64402000000
>   RequestDate:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 14:08:46 GMT
>   StatusMessage:OK
>   }

Funnily enough,I created a console app with the same code (even using the async methods) and it works fine but as soon as i debug on my phone (NOT on the emulator),I get that error. I have even updated all my nuget packages to the latest versions but no joy.

Below is the format of my query,like I said,this works in console app but weirdly has stopped on my windows phone (8) app project.

```
var tbData= tableClient.GetTableReference("MyTable");
string pkFilter =  TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",QueryComparisons.Equal, "MyKey");
TableQuery<MyClass> query = new TableQuery<MyClass>().Where(pkFilter);
var ptb = await tbData.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
```

Comment: It looks like the data is not loaded completely. Could you try by fetching smaller number of records say 10 or 100 instead of 1000?

Comment: hi @GauravMantri , the records Im attempting to fetch arent that many..i.e 30...same code works just fine in a console app but not in windows phone app?